# Error creating nested table column storage table

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Seeking help from experts to resolve the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE "ABC" 
   (----
    ----
    "STATUSES" "INTLIST" , 
    ---- 
    "CHAIN_DETAILS" "CHAIN_CFG_LIST" , 
    -----
   ) 
 NESTED TABLE "STATUSES" STORE AS "OP_STATUSES_NT" 
 RETURN AS VALUE
 NESTED TABLE "CHAIN_DETAILS" STORE AS "op_chains" 
 RETURN AS VALUE;
```

Gives error message:

> ORA-02320: Error creating nested table column storage table STATUSES
>   ORA-01950: no permissions for tablespace

Comment: I'm not an expert in Oracle but I'm pretty sure that "no permissions for tablespace" means that you don't have the permission to execute the operation.

Comment: Can you create other tables in that tablespace? (Since no tablespace is specified, I assume this is using the user's default tablespace.) What is your space quota (query `user_ts_quotas`) and what is `deferred_segment_creation` set to?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the user has no quota on the default tablespace. You can find your default tablespace by querying `user_users`, or `dba_users` if checking a different user, and the quota from `user_ts_quotas` or `dba_ts_quotas`. A value of `-1` means unlimited. Join these to see your quota for the default tablespace:

```
select u.username
     , u.default_tablespace
     , tq.max_bytes
from   user_users u
       left join user_ts_quotas tq
            on  tq.tablespace_name = u.default_tablespace;
```

This will be a problem for any table, but if `deferred_segment_creation` is set to `true` (the default) then the error will only appear when you attempt to add a row to the table, as this is the first request for storage.

Now that I check, it seems a nested table requires storage immediately, which could explain why you get the error for a nested table column.

Example using test user 'demo':

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri May 11 10:41:51 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create user demo identified by demo;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table, create type to demo;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as `demo`:

```
SQL> conn demo/demo
Connected.

SQL> col username format a15
SQL> col default_tablespace format a20

SQL> select u.username
  2       , u.default_tablespace
  3       , tq.max_bytes
  4  from   user_users u
  5         left join user_ts_quotas tq
  6              on  tq.tablespace_name = u.default_tablespace;

USERNAME        DEFAULT_TABLESPACE    MAX_BYTES
--------------- -------------------- ----------
DEMO            USERS
```

My default tablespace is `USERS` and I have no quota on it, but I can create a table:

```
SQL> create table demotable(id integer);

Table created.
```

I only have a problem when I need some actual storage:

```
SQL> insert into demotable values (1);
insert into demotable values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

Now try with a nested table:

```
SQL> create or replace type demo_tt as table of number(1);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table abc
  2  ( id integer
  3  , statuses demo_tt )
  4  nested table statuses store as op_statuses_nt return as value;
create table abc
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02320: failure in creating storage table for nested table column STATUSES
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

My user `demo` needs a quota on tablespace `USERS` (normally you grant `unlimited` or nothing, but just for fun let's allocate 1MB...)

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> alter user demo quota 1M on users;

User altered.

SQL> conn demo/demo
Connected.

SQL> select u.username
  2       , u.default_tablespace
  3       , tq.max_bytes
  4  from   user_users u
  5         left join user_ts_quotas tq
  6              on  tq.tablespace_name = u.default_tablespace;

USERNAME        DEFAULT_TABLESPACE    MAX_BYTES
--------------- -------------------- ----------
DEMO            USERS                   1048576
```

Retry the table creation:

```
SQL> create table abc
  2  ( id integer
  3  , statuses demo_tt )
  4  nested table statuses store as op_statuses_nt return as value;

Table created.

SQL> insert into abc (id, statuses) values (1, demo_tt(1,2,3));

1 row created.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot William for taking time to answer the question. I understood the root cause, that you explained.  I am getting similar error while creating tables having LOB columns.  ORA-60019 : 
Creating initial extent of size 14 in tablespace of extent size 8 . Do you think, the issue is same ?